# Initializing renv causes RStudio to collapse

Tags: r, fatal-error, jit, renv

I recently installed both R and RStudio on a new computer, and wanted to create an RProject. I used to use the package *renv* before and it worked pretty well so far.

However, when I tried to initialize the renv library it first created all the necessary folders within the Rproject, but then suddenly gives th following error:

`Fehler in data[[1]] . Indizierung ausserhalb der Grenzen`

Afterwards it says: *Fataler Fehler: unable to initialize the JIT*

[image]

And finally produces a fatal error and collapses.

I already un- and reinstalled both R and RStudio twice, but without success.
Any ideas?

````
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Switzerland.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Switzerland.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Switzerland.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                        LC_TIME=German_Switzerland.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.5          plyr_1.8.6          compiler_3.6.3      pillar_1.4.3        later_1.0.0         shinyjs_1.1        
 [7] tools_3.6.3         digest_0.6.25       viridisLite_0.3.0   jsonlite_1.7.0      lifecycle_0.1.0     tibble_2.1.3       
[13] gtable_0.3.0        pkgconfig_2.0.3     rlang_0.4.7         shiny_1.4.0         DBI_1.1.0           rstudioapi_0.11    
[19] crosstalk_1.0.0     RPostgreSQL_0.6-2   yaml_2.2.1          xfun_0.12           fastmap_1.0.1       stringr_1.4.0      
[25] httr_1.4.1          dplyr_0.8.4         vctrs_0.2.3         htmlwidgets_1.5.1   DT_0.12             tidyselect_1.0.0   
[31] leaflet_2.0.3       grid_3.6.3          data.table_1.12.8   glue_1.3.1          R6_2.4.1            plotly_4.9.2       
[37] reshape2_1.4.3      tidyr_1.0.2         purrr_0.3.3         ggplot2_3.2.1       magrittr_1.5        shinycssloaders_0.3
[43] scales_1.1.0        promises_1.1.0      htmltools_0.5.0     assertthat_0.2.1    mime_0.9            xtable_1.8-4       
[49] colorspace_1.4-1    httpuv_1.5.2        config_0.3          tinytex_0.20        stringi_1.4.6       lazyeval_0.2.2     
[55] munsell_0.5.0       crayon_1.3.4       ```
````

Comment: Please try first with the most recent R, Rstudio, and package versions to check if the error is a bug that has been fixed.

Comment: I tried with R 4.0.2 as well, producing the same result. I went back to R 3.6.3 since my colleagues who I work together with use this version as well.

Comment: Well, if you are sure that the packages were build for R 3.6.3 and not for R 4.0.2, you should direct your issue there: https://github.com/rstudio/renv/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue